# What is the solution of equation $z^2 - 2 \bar{z} = 3$?

Tags: complex-numbers

my question is how to solve the equation $z^2 - 2 \bar{z} = 3$, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$?

I know that polar form of any complex number is $z = r \cos(\varphi) + i \cdot r \sin (\varphi)$. And similarly $\bar{z} = r \cos(\varphi) - i \cdot r \sin(\varphi)$. But now, when I plug in into equation, I'm getting a little confused.

So, $(r \cos(\varphi) + i \cdot r \sin(\varphi))^{2} - 2(r \cos(\varphi) - i \cdot r \sin(\varphi)) = 3$, but now I don't know how to solve this equation.

Comment: Well, evaluate the squared term, and use the identity, $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$. Then, use Simon's favorite factoring trick.

Comment: By inspection $z=-1$ is a solution.

Comment: Write $z=a+bi$, expand, and compare real and imaginary parts.

Answer (score 4):

We have
$$z^2-2\overline z=3=\overline z^2-2z$$
Therefore
\begin{align}
&z^2-\overline z^2+2z-2\overline z=0\\
\implies &(z-\overline z)(z+\overline z+2)=0\\
\implies &\overline z = z\qquad\text{or}\qquad\overline z=-2-z
\end{align}
Putting these one by one in original equation, we get, $\boxed{z=-1,3}$ are the only solutions.

Answer (score 2):

In a problem like this, I prefer Cartesian coordinates, where $z = x + iy.$

> $z^2 - 2 \bar{z} = 3$

Therefore $(x + iy)^2 - 2(x - iy) = 3 \implies $

$(x^2 - y^2 - 2x - 3) + i(2xy + 2y) = 0 + i(0)$.

Therefore, $(2y)(x + 1) = 0$.

Therefore, either $y = 0$ or $x = -1$.

$y = 0 \implies (x^2 - 2x - 3) = 0 \implies (x - 3)(x + 1) = 0 \implies x \in \{3, -1\}.$

$x = -1 \implies 3 - y^2 - 3 = 0 \implies y = 0.$

Therefore, the possible answers are $(-1 + i[0], 3 + i[0]).$